# opening second angular application from first angular application

Tags: angular

I have two angular applications hosted in two different ports.

For example, **my-app1** and **my-app2**, **my-app1** hosted in localhost:4200 and **my-app2** hosted in localhost:4210 in same system. I have login / register functionality in my first angular application (**my-app1**) which is going to be accessed first by user.

Now I have a link / button in **my-app1** , whenever it is clicked. It should open second angular application (**my-app2**) which is already hosted in some other port in same system and if possible, also want to send Authorization token from **my-app1** to **my-app2** whenever it's routed to **my-app2**.

Comment: If auth is all about a auth token then send it via route params or query params

Comment: but first, I need to know how to open second angular application from first.

Comment: location.href `http://localhost:4210` but this will be problem when you move to production

Comment: Can I upload a my-app2 project inside the my-app1 ?

Comment: @Zohid No, It should be opened in a new tab and that too it should be a seperate application.

Comment: Sending the token in the path of the redirect url would be a really bad idea in my opinion. What ist your use case ? Why do you need to separate auth from the other parts of the application ? A better practice would be to store a session back end side, and request it when arriving in your second application I guess